# Error after running http-server command when turning my Angular App into a PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to turn my angular project into a progressive web app, I've been following the [angular official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#initial-load) , and after running this command

`http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/backoffice`

I got this error

```
 Starting up http-server, serving dist/backoffice
Available on:
  http://192.168.100.13:8080
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Wed May 27 2020 12:48:41 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)]  "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
[Wed May 27 2020 12:48:41 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)]  "GET /robots.txt" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
[Wed May 27 2020 12:48:41 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)]  "GET /robots.txt" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed May 27 2020 12:48:41 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)]  "GET /" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Comment: Can you give more context? 
Maybe a git repo or sandbox so we can see the actual code?

Comment: can u add the routing file?

Comment: `export const routes: Routes = [
 
 {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
      }
],
 
 {
    path: 'authentication',
    loadChildren: () => import('./manage-user/manage-user.module').then(m => m.ManageUserModule)
  },

];`